# MacOS and split DNS

Tags: vpn, dns

MacOS: 10.13.3

Pritunl VPN client: v1.0.1653.28

I have been following this: https://lists.apple.com/archives/macnetworkprog/2005/Sep/msg00047.html and http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20050621051643993

Both are old links. Searching around does suggest this is still the right method though.

I am trying to set it up so any queries for mydomain.com go to the DNS server on the other end of the Pritunl VPN. Anything else goes out on my normal default DNS settings (not via the VPN).

I have tried adding to both `State:/Network/Interface/utun0/IPv4/DNS` (appears to be the Pritunl VPN) and `State:/Network/Servoce/<id-identified-in-/Network/Gloal/IPv4>/DNS`

If I add it to utun0 nothing shows up in `scutil --dns` and if I do it on the global one it overwrites the default.

```
sudo scutil
open
d.init
d.add ServerAddresses * 1.2.3.5
d.add SupplementalMatchDomains mydomain.com
d.show
set State:/Network/Interface/utun0/IPv4/DNS
quit
```

What am I doing wrong?